# C#: Change format Day with Leading zero In DateTime

Tags: c#

in C#,
`DateTime.Day.Now.ToString()` is returning `1`. How can i get it as `01`?

Comment: did you mean DateTime.Now.Day.ToString()?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Two quick methods

```
DateTime.Now.Day.ToString("00");
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");
```

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
DateTime.Now.Day.ToString("00");
```

Comment: did you mean DateTime.Now.Day.ToString("00")?

Answer (score 9):

DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

edit: this assumes the questioner wanted the full date formatted with a double-digit day. If he wanted the day only, then other answers are better.

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime.Now.Day.ToString("D2")
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of how to format a date time in C#

You can use different formatting options behind the \ to make the date appear however you want.

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;

// use the current date/time to configure the output directory
String dateTime = String.Format( "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", currentDate);
```

Comment: Thx mate, this was from other code I had so I probably got the indexes mucked up.

Answer (score 4):

use format specifier

```
$"{today.Year}{today.Month:00}{today.Day:00}";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(DateTime.Now.Day < 10)
     return "0" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
else return DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");
```

Answer (score 1):

This works universally for any number: `myNumber.ToString("00")`