# String format options for int in .NET

Tags: c#, string

I want to convert an int to a string but if it is a single digit I want to add a leading 0

Is that one of the built in format options? or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562411/c-change-format-day-with-leading-zeron-in-datetime

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be achieved with normal string formats:

```
3.ToString("00");
```

Will result in the string "03".

See [custom numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) on MSDN and their [outputs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x5bacwt%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).