# C# DateTime Formatting to output 01/01/2000

Tags: c#, datetime-format, date-formatting

Currently my code reads:
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
The output is 1/1/2000.

I would like it to format as 01/01/2000.
Or how would I change the order so it reads as 2000/01/01.

I'm tying the date into the file name when I save and exit the application.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2562433) in the first duplicate I easily found. Or any of the other numerous related/similar/identical questions already on the site.

Comment: If you're going to code you  need to learn how to research. Googling "C# DateTime Formatting" reveals numerous resources that would easily answer this question. Asking a question every time you run into a basic issue like this will make the process very, very slow. Research and try some code first next time.

Answer (score -1):

.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");

or

.ToString("yyyy/dd/MM");

depending on your format.